# Flutter - implementing an horizontal, scrollable list of buttons placed at the bottom of the screen

Tags: listview, flutter

I am new to Flutter. I would like to implement an horizontal, scrollable list of buttons placed at the bottom of the screen (like, for example, the effect list of Instagram). The following code produce a list of buttons, but every button height fill the entire screen:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold( 
      appBar: AppBar( title: Text("Sample App") ),
      body: getEffectsWidget());
}


getEffectsWidget() {

  return ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: _getListData() );
}


_getListData() {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    widgets.add(Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child:FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => {},
              color: Colors.orange,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column( // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.add),
                  Text("Add")
                ],
              )
          )
      )
    );
  }
  return widgets;
}
```

I have tried to wrap the `ListView` inside a `Column` container with `mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment.end` but i get the following exception:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (23983): Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter (23983): Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match
I/flutter (23983): their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of
I/flutter (23983): vertical space in which to expand.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your `FlatButton` inside a `Column`, then create a widget above `FlatButton` (inside Column) wrapped by `Expanded` to cover all the space available and your `FlatButton` will be placed at the bottom.

```
      _getListData() {
        List<Widget> widgets = [];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          widgets.add(Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () => {},
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(
                        // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
                        children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.add), Text("Add")],
                      )),
                ],
              )));
        }
        return widgets;
      }
```

[image]